# Concat filepath & filename in Logic App to delete file from SFTP VM

Tags: azure, delete-file, azure-logic-apps

Concat filepath & filename in Logic App to delete file from SFTP VM.

Using Connector In logic App:- "SFTP-SSH"-->"Delete file"

My static path would be /a/b/c/"child directories"/"filename"

Child directories-will be having Multiple child dir like -1,2,3.. & with dynamic filename.

Comment: Hi Anirudh, I have provided my logic app below for your reference. If you need to delete dynamic filename, you can also use "List files in folder" action to get all of the filenames and use a "For each" before the "Initialize variable" and loop it to delete all of the filename which you want.

Comment: Hi Anirudh, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problems, please feel free to let me know. If the solution works fine, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Comment: I wen through your design, used a part of it & Thanks, its working fine with some of my efforts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my logic app, you can refer to the screenshot.

[image]

You just need to use "[List files in folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpconnector/#list-files-in-folder-[deprecated])" action to list all of the child directories under the "/A/B/C" and then use "[For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop)" to loop the body from "List files in folder". In the "For each" action, concat the path and the filename and do the delete operation.

Need to explain, the structure of my sftp directory is:

```
upload
  A
    B
      C
        childdirectory1
           file1.csv
           file2.csv
        childdirectory2
           file1.csv
           file2.csv
        childdirectory3
           file1.csv
           file2.csv
```

By the way, in the "For each" action, you'd better do this configuration as below (click the "..." button in the upper right corner of "For each" --> click "Settings" and then enable "Concurrency Control" and set the "Degree of Parallelism" to 1):
[image]

Hope it helps~